SNR calculation
I want to calculate the SNR of the following signal (the blue signal):
The signal peak value is: 0.0292 V
The noise peak value is: 0.0012 V

Based on the following formula:
SNR=20 log(Vp-Signal/Vp-noise)
I can calculate the SNR= 27 dB, is this  calculation correct?
I wanted to verify my hand calculation with MATLAB by the following code:
all=OPA656d(2:end,2);  // Signal
signal=all-mean(all);  // I removed the DC offset
snrOPA656din  =snr(signal,OPA656d(2:end,3));  //SNR calculation
the Result SNR= 64.4 dB
Why there is this much difference? is something wrong in my hand calculation or in my MATLAB code? or i missing something.
Regards

Defining a random signal such noise as a peak amplitude doesn't make a lot of sense since you might have a single random peak that is very high even while most of the noise is much weaker. Usually you would use a statistical measure of the noise's characteristics such as standard deviation, average power. etc.

It all depends how you define SNR, there is not a 'the SNR'.
Unfortunately, peak is not a robust way to define a signal or noise level. It's sensitive to small variations, and bandwidth and duration definitions. If you define SNR as peak signal / peak noise, then your first calculation is numerically correct, as far as it can be. This sort of definition was used in the early days of radio and radar, and was known as the 'tangential sensitivity'. That is, when the signal is observed on an oscilloscope, what you will see is the peaks of the signal poking above the peaks of the noise.
The energy of the signal, and the energy of the noise you have to handle, are the more modern ways to handle SNR calculations. Energy and power are much easier to measure, and be statistically confident about, than peaks.
How much noise do you have to handle? The signal appears to be both time limited, and bandwidth limited. If your detection processing filters the channel to the bandwidth limit, and/or gates the channel to the time limit, then correspondingly less noise will enter into your computation.
Of the many ways to define SNR, the one that makes most sense to you is the one that matches how you will actually be detecting the signal. Which definition is the MATLAB code using?

Your signal is not the highest peak of any single pulse you see so you are not calculating SNR, you are just calculating the relation between peaks of noise and peak of your signal in dB just like you said.
Your signal is some burst of a few sine wave cycles with some rise and decay in amplitude. Your noise is something that is added to it. You need some other way to know what is the waveform of your ideal signal without noise, and compare that with the noisy signal you actually have in the picture.

Thanks for the answer, so you mean this formula is wrong 20 log(Vp-Signal/Vp-noise)? then should I just trust the MATLAB result?

I also should mentioned that I need to just calculate the SNR for a specific region, e,g form -1 to 2 second in the picture.

@Andromeda You are telling Matlab to calculate the SNR between your signal with DC offset removed and the original signal. The Matlab webpage says the first parameter is the signal and the second parameter is the noise, so I don't think you use the function in a way that it gives you the SNR of your signal and your noise.
